Using Manipulate to Plot a Function and its Minima for a Changing Parameter
I want to display the function
$$ f(\phi)=E\bigg(\phi \log{\phi} + (1-\phi) \log{(1-\phi)}+\chi\phi(1-\phi) \bigg)$$
I have that $E=.505$. Now dependent on the value of $\chi$, the function $f$ has either one or three minima. I want to create a plot in Mathematica using the Manipulate function which displays $f(\phi)$ over $\phi \in [0,1]$, however, I also want to display how the minima are shifting with the changing $\chi$. I have the following lines of code:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[\[Phi]_, \[Chi]_] = 
    E1 (\[Phi] Log[10, \[Phi]] + (1 - \[Phi]) Log[10, 
    1 - \[Phi]] + \[Chi] \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]))
E1 = 5.05 10^-1;
roots = Solve[D[f[\[Phi], \[Chi]], \[Phi]] == 0 /. \[Chi] -> 1, 
    Assumptions -> 0 <= \[Phi] <= 1]
Manipulate[Plot[{f[\[Phi], \[Chi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 1}], {\[Chi], 0, 3}]

The last command will output the plot I want for $f(\phi)$ and the command immediately before will find the roots I want for one specific value of $\chi$ (in this case $\chi=1$). Is there any easy way to incorporate this into my manipulate plot? That is, I would love for the plot to have red points that mark the different critical values of the function for the value of $\chi$ that is currently being plotted. Any help would be much appreciated.
I realized that I could use the GridLines command to add these vertical lines as follows:
Manipulate[
   Plot[{f[\[Phi], \[Chi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 1}, 
   GridLines -> {{\[Phi] /. roots[[1]], \[Phi] /. 
   roots[[2]], \[Phi] /. roots[[3]]}, {}}], {\[Chi], 
   0, 1}]

However, these rely on the Solve command which requires I fix a value for $\chi$. Is there anyway to keep the Solve command for general $\chi$ so that these gridlines also change with the function and are always at the critical points?
Note that one potential issue is that for $\chi<.87$ we have only one real solution while for $\chi \geq .87$ we have three real solutions.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

E1 = 505/1000;

f[\[Phi]_, \[Chi]_] = 
  E1 (\[Phi] Log[10, \[Phi]] + (1 - \[Phi]) Log[10, 
       1 - \[Phi]] + \[Chi] \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]));

argMin[\[Chi]v_?NumericQ] := Module[{\[Chi] = Rationalize[\[Chi]v, 0]},
  Solve[{D[f[\[Phi], \[Chi]], \[Phi]] == 0, 
    D[f[\[Phi], \[Chi]], {\[Phi], 2}] > 0}, \[Phi], Reals,
   Assumptions -> 0 <= \[Phi] <= 1, Method -> Reduce]]

argMax[\[Chi]v_?NumericQ] := Module[{\[Chi] = Rationalize[\[Chi]v, 0]},
  Solve[{D[f[\[Phi], \[Chi]], \[Phi]] == 0, 
    D[f[\[Phi], \[Chi]], {\[Phi], 2}] < 0}, \[Phi], Reals,
   Assumptions -> 0 <= \[Phi] <= 1, Method -> Reduce]]

#[0] & /@ {argMin, argMax}


#[1] & /@ {argMin, argMax}


#[3] & /@ {argMin, argMax}


Manipulate[
 Module[{
   min = argMin[\[Chi]],
   max = argMax[\[Chi]]},
  Plot[{f[\[Phi], \[Chi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2],
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5],
     Blue,
     If[Length@min > 0, Point[{\[Phi], f[\[Phi], \[Chi]]} /. min], 
      Nothing],
     Red,
     If[Length@max > 0, Point[{\[Phi], f[\[Phi], \[Chi]]} /. max], 
      Nothing]}]],
 {{\[Chi], 1}, 0, 3, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]



This may be useful:
f[\[Phi]_, \[Chi]_] := E1 (\[Phi] Log[10, \[Phi]] + (1 - \[Phi]) 
                     Log[10, 1 - \[Phi]] + \[Chi] \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]));
E1 = 505/100;
Manipulate[
 roots = Solve[D[f[\[Phi], \[Chi]], \[Phi]] == 0, 
         Assumptions -> 0 <= \[Phi] <= 1];
 {Plot[{f[\[Phi], \[Chi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 1}], roots // N}, {\[Chi], 0, 3, 1/100}]

Since Solve was complaining that it needed to use exact numbers, I replaced the E1 value. The //N turns it back into a floating point number.
